# Why does $\vec{r}\,'(t)$ give the tangent vector to $\vec{r}(t)$ if $\vec{r}\,'(t)$ is orthogonal to $\vec{r}(t)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

I have seen a proof that $\vec{r}\,'(t)$ is orthogonal to $\vec{r}(t)$, but $\vec{r}\,'(t)$ gives the tangent vector to the curve $\vec{r}(t)$, for any $t$. I don't understand how $\vec{r}\,'(t)$ can represent the tangent vector but also be orthogonal to the vector curve?

Just another question related to the above:
If the binormal vector is defined to be $$\vec{B}(t) = \vec{T}(t) \times \vec{N}(t),$$ where $\vec{T}(t)$ and $\vec{N}(t)$ represent the unit tangent and unit normal vector respectively, does the binormal vector give a unit vector orthogonal to both the tangent and normal vector, in the direction according to the 'right hand rule'? What significance does this have?

Comment: In general the derivative of the position vector is not orthogonal to the position vector. Are you thinking of the derivative of the unit vector being orthogonal to the position vector?

Comment: Consider a circle: in such a case, the tangent vector is orthogonal to the position vector.

Comment: @Andrew I was just on [this page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TangentNormalVectors.aspx), where it gives a fact about the orthogonality about the derivative of a position vector, but I don't think I understand it.

Comment: That is assuming that $\left\|\vec{r}(t)\right\|$ is constant over time. In general though, $\vec{r}(t)$ need not be orthogonal to $\vec{r}'(t)$. However, it is certainly possible to happen, for example if $\vec{r}(t)$ is tracing out a circle centred at the origin.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth , like a circle, centred at the origin?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth why does finding the derivative of a tangent vector give the normal vector curve?

Comment: @Gurjinder in your link where it says the derivative (velocity) is orthogonal to the position vector it is referring to the case where the magnitude of the position vector is constant. I.e. it is describing the position of something moving in a circle in 2D or sphere in 3D centered at the origin. If it moves off this sphere then the derivative will no longer be orthogonal to the position.

Comment: I am under the impression that you are mixing two concepts : 1) the gradient $(\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)$ of a curve or a family of curves defined **implicitly** by $f(x,y)=0$, which indeed is normal to the curve (in the sense that it is orthogonal to the tangent of the curve at any point) 2) the tangent $(x'(t),y'(t))$ to a curve defined **parametrically** by $(x=x(t),y=y(t))$  which indicates the direction of the curve.

Comment: @Andrew Ahh okay cool. Also on the page it gives a formula for the unit normal vector for a position vector curve, by differentiating the unit tangent vector. Why does differentiating the tangent vector give a vector orthogonal to the tangent vector (and also orthogonal to the vector curve)?

Comment: Differentiating the tangent vector gives a vector orthogonal to the tangent vector because the tangent vector is a unit vector - unit vectors are vectors that lie in a unit sphere (sphere with radius 1), and for the same reason mentioned previously such vectors have orthogonal derivatives.

Comment: Remember that $r(t)$ is a vector from the origin to a point on the curve. The tangent vector points in a direction along the curve.

Comment: > "Why does differentiating the tangent vector give a vector orthogonal to the tangent vector ?" : a straightforward explanation is that if you have $\|\vec{r}(t)\|^2=1$ and you write it as $\vec{r}(t)^2=1$, differentiating this last identity wrt $t$ gives $2 \vec{r}(t). \vec{r'}(t)=0$ which means that  $\vec{r}(t) \perp \vec{r'}(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help make sense of this think of $r(t)$ as your position as you are driving around on earth (approximated as a sphere). The tangent vector $T(t)$ is the direction your car is facing. The normal vector $N(t)$ is the direction you're turning your steering wheel (left or right). The binormal vector is a vector orthogonal to both (pointing up or down).